# What makes sour beers sour?

Tags: taste, brewing, sour-beer

I like sour beers and am curious what makes them sour. What's the process that results in the range of sourness?

Comment: Are you looking for the reason behind the sour flavor or an explanation of the process that makes sour beer?

Answer (score 4):

From the [Wiki page on Sour Beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sour_beer):

"[S]our beers are made by intentionally allowing wild yeast strains or bacteria into the brew. Traditionally, Belgian brewers allowed wild yeast to enter the brew naturally through the barrels or during the cooling of the wort in a coolship open to the outside air – an unpredictable process that many modern brewers avoid.

The most common agents used to intentionally sour beer are Lactobacillus, Brettanomyces, and Pediococcus. Another method for achieving a tart flavor is adding fruit during the aging process to spur a secondary fermentation or contribute microbes present on the fruit's skin."

Answer (score 1):

Try to see if this site you can find all the info you need
[6 Tips on How to Brew Sour Beers](https://www.homebrewersassociation.org/how-to-brew/6-tips-brew-sour-beers-mad-fermentationist/)